# Usar selenium sem abrir navegador

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Como usar o selenium sem abrir o navegador?

Eu utilizei um código que vi aqui mesmo,  `options.add_argument("--headless")`, e também `options.set_headless(True)`, mas dá esse erro:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_spanClosingPrice"]"}

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcc22fc0c43eb8c6a88ce92fd344108cf8f690c21da57a3fb0d8dadcd207d5de3")
resultado = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_spanClosingPrice"]').text
print(resultado)
driver.quit()
```

O que fazer? Estou utilizando Python.

*OBS: quando deixo abrir o navegador ele acha certinho.*

Comment: Você poderia, por favor, colocar o código para que nós possamos entender melhor o seu problema? Obrigado!

Comment: botei o codigo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso não precise ser utilizando **Selenium + WebDriver** você pode utilizar o **requests + BeautifulSoup**:

---

Importando as bibliotecas necessárias e criando o cabeçalho para não receber erro 403(Forbidden)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cabecalho = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}
pagina = 'https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcc22fc0c43eb8c6a88ce92fd344108cf8f690c21da57a3fb0d8dadcd207d5de3'
dados = requests.get(pagina, headers = cabecalho)
```

Criando o objeto soup:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(dados.text, 'html.parser')
```

Aqui extraímos a informação :

```py
soup.find('span',{'id': 'ContentPlaceHolder1_spanClosingPrice'}).text
```

Resultado:

```py
'$264.47 / ETH'
```

Dessa forma você não precisa abrir browser.

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou muito

Comment: por nada! Abraço!!

Answer (score 0):

Faltou importar Options!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'chromedriver.exe', options = options)
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcc22fc0c43eb8c6a88ce92fd344108cf8f690c21da57a3fb0d8dadcd207d5de3")
resultado = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_spanClosingPrice"]').text
print(resultado)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Aqui da o mesmo erro que ela cita acima: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde,

Dê uma olhada em PhantomJS
https://phantomjs.org/download.html

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("url")
print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```